# Contar caracteres string

Tags: php, string

Estou a contar os caracteres de uma string em PHP. O conteudo da string é: 10,12,12,22,33.
Quero percorer para imprimir um a um e com um "\n". O problema é que utilizo o strlen, e conta todos os caracteres incluindo as vírgulas. Queria com contasse um caractere so depois da vírgula. O código que utilizei:

```
$max= strlen($positionY); // 6
for($i=0; $i<$max; $i++){
    fwrite($hndl, $positionY[$i]);
    fwrite($hndl, "\n");
}
```

Comment: Se utilizares o Split resolve o teu problema?

Comment: Faz um Replace e remove as virgulas

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Pelo que pude entender da pergunta, você deseja dividir a string pela virgula e contar a quantidade, deste modo:

```
$strTxt = '10,12,12,22,33';
$arrDividido = explode(',', $strTxt);
$intQtde = count($arrDividido); // Tem a quantidade de textos separados por virgulas

foreach($arrDividido as $strDiv) {
  echo $strDiv . '<br />';
}
/* Saida
10
12
12
22
33
*/
```

Funções utilizadas:

[count()](http://php.net/manual/pt_BR/function.count.php)

[explode()](http://php.net/manual/pt_BR/function.explode.php)

Comment: Isso mesmo, funciona perfeitamente.